# Transform a list to a map

Tags: scala

I have the following types:

```
case class Category(id: Int, name: String)
case class Product(id: Int, location: Location, categoryIdList: Option[List[Int]])
```

Given a list of products

```
val products:List[Product] = loadProducts()
```

How can I product a map of categoryId to Location?

```
Map[categoryId, Location]
```

So my method would look something like this:

```
def getMap(products: List[Product]): Map[Int, Location] = {
   ??
}
```

I need to somehow iterate over the optional list of categoryIdList and then create a map from that with the Location property.

Comment: What happens if two product have the same categoryId but different locations? Your `Map` as declared would lose information about one of them.

Comment: @Daenyth just ignore that for now, in my use case it won't happen

Comment: Also, `Option[List[Int]]` isn't a very useful type - semantically you're saying "Product may or may not have a a list of categoryIds which may or may not be empty". Better would be `Option[NonEmptyList]` instead, or if you want more efficient getMap, then `Set[Int]` would be better

Comment: Do you have a case where, there will be `categoryId`  with multiple `Locations`? If yes, then `Map[Int, List[Location]]` or `MultiMap[Int, Location]` will be required.

Comment: Have you accepted an answer on this question

Answer (score 3):

In order to convert a `Seq` to a `Map` we need to first convert it to be a `Seq[(Int,Location)]`, that is a `Seq` of a `Tuple2`. Only then will the `toMap` method actually be available.

Edit: Okay here's an implementation based on each categoryId on the list, note that you shouldn't use an option of a list, since an empty state for a List is just an empty list.

```
def getMap(products: List[Product]): Map[Int, Location] = {
   products.flatMap(toListTuple2).toMap
} 

def toListTuple2(product: Product): List[(Int, Location)] = {
  product.categoryIdList
    .getOrElse(List())
    .map(category => (category, product.location))
}
```

So here we first turn our product into a list of `categoryId`s and `Locations` and then `flatmap` it to a `List` of `(Int, Location)`, which can then be turned into a `Map` by calling `toMap`.

Comment: The product class has a list of categoryId, it is in the case class.

Comment: Yes, but which one in the list do you want? a `Map[Int, Location]` only has one, no?

Comment: for each product it has to loop through all the categories and create a map between each categoryId and the Location for the product.

Comment: Hmm., thanks!  I actually need to return a Map[Int, Seq[Location]].  does effect it allot?

Comment: Well, what kind of `Location`s would the `Seq` include?

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you are asking for however solution doesn't address problems provided in comments:

```
def getMap(products: List[Product]): Map[Int, Location] = {
  val locations = scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int, Location]()
  for {
    product <- products
    if product.categoryIdList.nonEmpty
    category <- product.categoryIdList.get
  } { 
    locations(category) = product.location
  }
  locations.toMap
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def getMap(products: List[Product]) = {
      products.map(p => (p.categoryIdList.getOrElse(List.empty), p.location))
              .flatMap(x => x._1.map(_ -> x._2))
              .toMap
}
```